# How to specify the order in which the style sheets appear in the document?

Tags: material-ui

I have several styled components, using the `withStyles` HOC to export them, but i can't override some rules because jss mix the order of mui stylesheets with my component's stylesheets.

How can I push my styles to the end?

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Me and my team also stumbled upon this and we managed to find a solution. Apparently **withStyles**, takes an **option** object as parameter. So in order to solve this issue, you need to pass a parameter **index** with a value of **1**. So what you get is this:

```
withStyles(styles, {index: 1})(yourComponent)
```

Comment: According to this (very strict) community rules, I can't say thanks. I can't upvote your answer either because I suck at stackoverflow and my reputation is too low. But your answer solved my problem. Sooo... thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This is covered [here](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/css-in-js/#css-injection-order) in the documentation for the Material UI library.

> **CSS injection order**
>   The CSS injected by Material-UI to style a component has the highest specificity possible as the `<link>` is injected at the bottom of the `<head>` to ensure the components always render correctly.
>
> You might, however, also want to override these styles, for example with styled-components. If you are experiencing a CSS injection order issue, JSS provides a mechanism to handle this situation. By adjusting the placement of the `insertionPoint` within your HTML head you can control the order that the CSS rules are applied to your components.

Essentially, you create an injection point, and then have JSS use that for where it inserts the styles.  The options in doing so include creating an HTML Comment, creating an HTML element, and using Javascript to create a comment in HTML (as `create-react-app` strips the comment in production)

Comment: Thank you and Yes, I've tried that. You can see the `<noscript id="jss-insertion-point">` tag just before the styles tags begin. But that just controls the insertion point of every stylesheet as a block. What I'm trying to achieve is to control the order of the stylesheets, so that my styles are at the end and correctly override mui styles