# Incorrect JSS style order - Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, themes, material-ui, jss, css-in-js

I have a situation the JSS styles of my MUI component library (**Styles A**) are superceding those provided by a consumer's website (**Styles B**).

Styles A is intended to overwritable by Styles B.

Take this minimal example:

**Styles A** (in Component Library)

```
const styles = theme => ({
    title: {
        color: 'red'
    }
});

const CollapsibleCard = ({classes, title}) => (
    <Typography className={classes.title} variant={"h6"}>
        {title}
    </Typography>
);

export default withStyles(styles)(CollapsibleCard);
```

**Styles B** (in Consumer site)

```
const styles = {
    title: {
        color: 'green'
    },
};

const Page = ({classes}) => (
    <CollapsibleCard
        title={"Testing"}
        classes={{
            title: classes.title
        }}
    />
);
export default withStyles(styles)(Page);
```

Resulting in the element having a cascading style of:

```
.CollapsibleCard-title-160 {
    color: red;
}
.Page-title-157 {
    color: green;
}
```

Where green from Styles B is being overwritten by red from Styles A.

---

**Edit**: The reason behind this order appears to be the order in which MUI (specifically the `withStyle()` function) injects stylesheets.

[image: css order screenshot]

While this can be fixed (as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49180192/how-to-specify-the-order-in-which-the-style-sheets-appear-in-the-document)) by passing an index in the withStyles options, i.e: `export default withStyles(styles, {index: 1})(Page);`. This doesn't seem to be the most efficient/effective approach in a library context.

Is there a way to dictate the order of the MUI styles < Component Library styles < Consumer styles without declaring the index for each withStyles?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: @JeevaJsb this was a while ago now, but I don't think we found a solution outside of the noted workaround. Haven't investigated in later versions of MUI

Comment: I have solved this by changing the import order in the component

Comment: @JeevaJsb that makes sense; you should add this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, the import order was incorrect. So the JSS style order is incorrect and the theme was overridden.

We need to make sure which style should be applied. So based on that we need to change the import order. This will help to solve the issue.